# Change names of lists at once

Tags: r, list, purrr, stringr

I have lists and I want their names to be in lower letters.
I don't want to use a for-loop, I want to use a function of `purrr`

```
> library(purrr)
> a <- list(Header = 1, Body = 1)
> b <- list(Header = 3, Body = 2)
> list(a, b) %>%
+   walk(~ {names(.x) <<- str_to_lower(names(.x))})
> a
$Header
[1] 1

$Body
[1] 1

> b
$Header
[1] 3

$Body
[1] 2
```

The names should be `"header"` and `"body"`. 
Why does this not work? I explicitly used `<<-` and not `<-` but the names don't change. What can I do?

Comment: Still the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(purrr)
a <- list(Header = 1, Body = 1)
b <- list(Header = 3, Body = 2)
```

I guess you intend to change global variables by `purrr::walk`. Here is a choice to make the symbol **`"<<-"`** work:

```
c("a", "b") %>%
  walk(~ eval(parse(text = paste0("names(", ., ")<<-tolower(names(", ., "))"))))
```

In addition, you can use `assign(..., pos = 1)` to change global variables.

```
list(a = a, b = b) %>%
  iwalk(~ assign(.y, set_names(.x, tolower(names(.x))), pos = 1))
```

*Check*

```
a

# $header
# [1] 1
# 
# $body
# [1] 1

b

# $header
# [1] 3
# 
# $body
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not?

```
names(a) <- tolower(names(a))
names(b) <- tolower(names(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want a global assignment to lower case names. To do this for all selected objects `c("a", "b")` at once, in a function you may `get` them from global environment, lower the names, and `assign` the transformed objects to the old ones (overwrite).

```
lapply(c("a", "b"), function(x) {
  d <- get(x, envir=.GlobalEnv)
  names(d) <- tolower(names(d))
  assign(x, d, envir=.GlobalEnv)
})

names(a)
# [1] "header" "body"  
names(b)
# [1] "header" "body"
```

---

*Data*

```
a <- list(Header = 1, Body = 1)
b <- list(Header = 3, Body = 2)
```